# What are some proposals for a post-war Gaza that doesn't involve the expansion of Israel security buffer zone?

Tags: israel, gaza

https://www.timesofisrael.com/israel-in-talks-with-congo-and-other-countries-on-gaza-voluntary-migration-plan/

> On Tuesday, during a conference held in the Knesset to examine
> possibilities for postwar Gaza, Gamliel said: “At the end of the war,
> Hamas rule will collapse. There are no municipal authorities; the
> civilian population will be entirely dependent on humanitarian aid.
> There will be no work, **and 60% of Gaza’s agricultural land will become
> security buffer zones.”**
>
> In internal discussions, Gamliel presented a map of the Gaza Strip
> after the fighting that shows remaining residents boxed in. Israel
> would cut ties with Gaza **and expand its security buffer zones;** control
> the Philadelphi Corridor, which runs along the 14-kilometer (8.7-mile)
> Gaza-Egypt border (a plan attacked by an Egyptian lawmaker on Saturday
> after it was announced by Netanyahu); and establish a permanent naval
> blockade.

What are some proposals for a post-war Gaza that doesn't involve the expansion of Israel security buffer zone? Is there any proposal being seriously considered that doesn't involve that? I think Egypt came up with a plan, and I heard Israel did not outright reject the plan, but I am not sure it involved the expansion of Israel security buffer zone.

Comment: The very article you quoted from talks about Israels idea to 'voluntarily relocate' the population of Gaza to somewhere far away. That wouldn't require a buffer zone in Gaza afterwards because there would be no Palistinians in Gaza anymore.

Comment: Israel would like to send all Gazan Palestinians (who have managed to survive) to [Congo](https://www.msn.com/en-gb/news/world/israel-in-secret-talks-to-send-gazans-to-congo-as-part-of-resettlement-plan/ar-AA1mpRzm) apparently.

Comment: Would the elimination of Gaza via their expulsion to Egypt count as such a proposal?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Another proposal, highly unacceptable to the US and many European states, but relatively popular among Palestinians, in many academic circles, and I would say in anti-Imperialist movements around the world, is: A reunification of Palestine into a single state.

Indeed, the logic of this arrangement runs diametrically against what we're seeing from Israel now in Gaza, and the massive killing and kidnapping of civilians by Gazans on October 7th 2023; but that does not mean it is utopian in the least (a point I won't elaborate on since that's outside the scope of this question).

One of the groups, or networks-of-groups, supporting this course of action has a (fancy-looking) website about it: https://www.odsi.co/ (ODS stands for One Democratic State). Another group created: https://onestatecampaign.org/en/ , with a 10-point manifesto, which I'll abridge here.

- **A Single Constitutional Democracy.** ...  a state belonging to all its citizens, including the Palestinian refugees. All citizens will enjoy equal rights. ...
- **Right of Return**, of Restoration and of Reintegration into Society.  ... of all Palestinian refugees and their descendants
- **Individual Rights.** No ... discriminat[ion] ... on the basis of ethnic identity, national or cultural belonging, ... color, gender, language, religion, political opinion, property or sexual orientation. ... right to freedom of movement ... right to reside anywhere in the country.  ... free thought and freedom of opinion. ... religious marriage [and] ... civil marriage.
- **Collective Rights.**  ... and the freedom of association, whether national, ethnic, religious, class or gender. ...  all languages, arts and cultures can flourish and develop ... No group or collectivity will have any privileges
- **Immigration**: Normal procedures of obtaining citizenship will be extended to those willing to immigrate to the country.
- **Shared Civil Society.**
- **Economy and Economic Justice.**  ... Economic policy must address the decades of exploitation and discrimination ... [unequal] income distribution ... a ... redistributive economic policy...
- **Commitment to Human Rights**, Justice and Peace. The State shall uphold international law and seek the peaceful resolution of conflicts...
- **Our Role in the Region.** The ODS Campaign will join with all progressive forces in the Arab world struggling for democracy, social justice and egalitarian societies free from tyranny and foreign domination. The State shall seek democracy and freedom in the Middle East ...
- **International responsibility**. ... part of ... striving for an alternative global order that shall be pluralistic and sustainable, more just, egalitarian and humanistic and free of exploitation, racism, intolerance, oppression, wars, colonialism and imperialism.

Note this will necessarily entail:

- Dissolution of Israel (as a Jewish state)
- Dissolution of the Palestinian authority / the rump-state of Palestine as it is structured at the moment
- Citizenship based on both jus soli and jus sanguinis in some combination
- Significant land reforms
- An easing of the overpopulation problem of the Gaza strip
- A significant immigration absorption challenge if several millions of the refugees outside Palestine were to decide to return

Comment: Perhaps it's popular in academic circles, but the evidence that a one-state solution is the preference of Palestinians seems to be lacking. 23% were in favor of the one democratic state option, behind both the two-state and one non-democratic state options. https://pcpsr.org/en/node/928

Comment: @Connor: 1. That poll counts the possibility of one state with unequal rights for non-native Palestinians. Many Palestinians support this, not willing to legitimize the colonizers' continued presence; and I can't say I blame them. One-state (or two-states) is a compromise position if that's not available. 2. Two-states is a "despair" position for many; they would tell you "ideally, I would have liked Palestine to be reunited, but what can you do, Israel is so powerful, we have to have _some_ kind of non-hellish existence etc."

Comment: 3. Two-states seems to always be on the table, is what most politicians and diplomats on both sides talk about; and one-staters are essentially enemies of the state both in the PA and in Israel. So explicitly adopting it is somewhat of a radical act. Still, I'll take that 23% - we can build on that. And if you examined the two-staters' interaction with one-staters (among Palestinians I mean), I think you would reach the same conclusion.

Comment: "Reunification" is a strange term considering that a unified "Palestine" (that includes all of Israel's territory) has *never* existed as an independent nation-state, only as a part of some larger empire (Roman, Caliphate, Ottoman, or British).

Comment: @dan04: That's fair, but: 1. I'm not a big fan of nation states. 2. Many nation-states are more oppressive of their citizens/subjects than some empires were. 3. TBH the very partition of the Arab East into the proto-nation-states is, well, an imperialist plot - literally, the UK and France plotted it - which has not benefited the people of the region overall. A federated arrangement should have been a better path for development and progress.

Answer (score 8):

A common proposal (not my proposal) is:

1. Withdrawal by Israel the pre-1967-war / 1949 armistice lines (UNSC resolution 242).
2. Recognition of the state of Palestine and, provisionally, both fragments of its government.
3. Cessation of future hostilities into out-of-1949 territory.
4. Cessation of the blockade on Gaza (that includes Egypt BTW).
5. Facilitation of freedom of movement between the west bank and gaza strip.
6. Absorption of the Palestinian refugees, particularly the large number of them currently living in the Gaza strip (UNSC 194) <- *Though in fact, most states having this general proposal don't really emphasize this part and kind of silently ignore it.*

To my knowledge, this is the most popular position in international diplomatic circles since Israel was formed, more or less.

Of course, this does not cover:

- Who foots the bill for reconstruction of Gaza city (it's tens of billions of USD of property damage)
- Who provides for the population of Gaza, with much of its society having collapsed by the carpet-bombing of the city and even some agricultural areas.
- How will a state of Palestine be able to govern itself given the difficulty of arranging for elections at the moment, on one hand, and the bifrucation between the WB and Gaza until now, on the other.

Comment: This is called *the Arab peace initiative* - this is neither a common proposal, nor the one supported by most western states (aka Oslo accords.)

Comment: @RogerV.: It is the rough official position, give or take some nuances, of most world states, including AFAICT all permanent members of the security council. It is also a very pro-Zionist position, in that it re-legitimizes the ethnic cleansing of the Palestinians in 1948.

Comment: If you view this proposal as legitimizing the Nakba, what do you view as a proposal that would not? I assume, or at least hope, that it is not "all non-Palestinians leave Israel," so what? A one-state solution (the United Republic of Palestine-Israel?) with equal rights for everyone currently living in both Israel and Palestine? A partition into two states, with different borders from those in the consensus position that you mentioned? The abolition of all national borders?

Comment: @Obie2.0: Well, I'm an Anarchist, and that's a deep discussion way beyond the scope of this comment exchange. But - a single democratic state is also a somewhat popular solution among Palestinians that, while difficult to achieve, would be much better than the current state of affairs.

Comment: By the way, to put all my cards on the table, I personally think a single plurinational state with true equality and equity between Arab, Jewish, and other citizens would be ideal, but one has to consider practical issues: right now people in the Israeli government are talking about using nuclear weapons on the Gaza Strip and expelling everyone to the Congo. Just ending the war and preventing Israel from annexing more territory already seems ambitious, the Arab Peace Plan seems barely conceivable, and the notion of an equitable one-state solution a distant pipe dream.

Comment: @Obie2.0: See my new answer.

Comment: @Obie2.0 *right now people in the Israeli government are talking about using nuclear weapons on the Gaza Strip and expelling everyone to the Congo.* - you are peddling conspiracy theories, presenting rants of some right-wing nuts as government policy and majority opinion. You are also bordering on racism when attributing it to all the *people in Israel* - einpoklum here is likely one of them, and likely not very exceptional in his views (he mostly channels the stuff that one routinely reads in Haaretz, and promoted by several political parties in the Israeli parliament and many Israeli NGOs.)

Comment: @RogerV. - I just said that people in the Israeli government had said it, which is true. Your idea that I was attributing it to everyone in Israel appears to have been created out of whole cloth.

Comment: @Obie2.0 I quoted what you wrote. And you clearly base your opinion on these statements rather than on what the Israeli public actually thinks.

Comment: @einpoklum *anarchist* is a pretty word, but not very relevant here - beyond the Bakunin's and Kropotkin's claims that it is human nature to live in peace with one's neighbors. Your view is more *assimilationist* - you think that, if only Jews stopped annoying Arabs and westerners, those would leave the Jews in peace and recognize them as equals. Whether it is any more true today than at the times if Herzl is open to a debate, but it certainly won't happen soon...

Comment: In reference to "carpet bombing".   I have an idea of what that means from WW2 videos.  Is anything even close to equivalent of that happening in Gaza?

Comment: @MichaelRichardson: Oh yes, it at a very similar level. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UogxCXvMLnk) is a bit of drone footage from over 2 months ago already; most of Gaza is in a similar state (i.e. not all buildings are like the ruined ones, but most buildings are like those in the vicinity of the ruined ones.) Some [more drone footage](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3-APSXZy9UI) from a couple of weeks back.

Comment: Combining two distinct nationalities into one state is difficult even under good circumstances (see Czechoslovakia), but is utterly impossible when one side (or both) wants the other one dead.

Comment: @dan04: The combination has already happened, albeit in a crappy way. Historic Palestine is controlled by a single state. And in its different areas, except Gaza which is really small, there live both non-Palestinian Israelis and native Palestinians.